# tsconfig path and webpack alias - cannot find module issue

Tags: reactjs, webpack, tsconfig

myCustom and ToDo are each react app and want to import MyCustom as a module inside ToDo app.

so following was my trial / folder structure:

```
[api]
|
[client]
|- [MyCustom]
|- [ToDo]
|  |- [src] (in src, will use - import {} from 'myCustom')
|  |- tsconfig.json (added "paths": { "myCustom": ["../myCustom/src"] })
|  |- package.json (added dependency - "myCustom": "1.0.0")
```

and in ToDo app, when I try `npm install`, it says `myCustom` is not in the npm registry. 
can you point out what's wrong here, please?

_____________________________ 
 
on TODO webpack.config.js file, I've added

```
resolve: {
   modules: ['../MyCustom/src']
},
resolveLoader: {
   modules: ['../MyCustom/src', 'myCustom']
}
```

and built failed with following error: 
 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'source-map-loader'.

Am I using a loader wrong?

Answer (score 0):

resolve is a main topic in webpack.

1. please read how to [resolve alias](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias) and don't work with '../' in webpack
2. then define where [modules](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve) can be found
3. define where [loaders](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolveloader) can be found

```
  
    // https://github.com/unic/darvin-webpack-boilerplate/blob/master/webpack.config.js
    const webpackConfigProd ={
        resolve: {
          modules: ['node_modules', '@yourAlias/yourCustomDir']
        },
        resolveLoader: {
          modules: ['node_modules', '@yourAlias/loaderDir']
        }
    };
```

Comment: Hello, then what's the next step? Should I build and then npm install?

Comment: @doobean please read the npm docs, your second question is out of webpack topic.

Comment: I've been trying your suggestion until now.. but sorry I can't find what's wrong. could you please check my updated question? @tfr